# How to make ImageView following my finger and rotate when moving with ImageView in Android?

Tags: android, rotation, imageview, move

Dear android experts I would like ask you how to make ImageView rotation when moving with it. I have picture of the plane. When I touch_down and moving with it, ImageView follow my finger and also dynamically rotate. When I touch finger up, the plane ImageView rotate up, when I touch left, ImageView  rotate dynamically to the left. Please can you show me the way ? I was looking for some examples and was able to work only with a fixed point on the screen, not with a moving object. I was working with examples, such as example [Calculate angle of touched point and rotate it in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926816/calculate-angle-of-touched-point-and-rotate-it-in-android) . But I have moving objects, can you help ?![picture what I need - dynamiccaly follow  finger and rotate it][1]

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 public class abc extends Activity implements OnTouchListener 
    {
 ImageView img;
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.one);

            img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            img.setOnTouchListener(this);
 }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
{
    switch (event.getAction())
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        {       
              // Here u can write code which is executed after the user touch on the screen 
                 break; 
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        {             
               // Here u can write code which is executed after the user release the touch on the screen    
             break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        {  
           // Here u can write code which is executed when user move the finger on the screen   
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

And also check this link,
  http://obviam.net/index.php/moving-images-on-the-screen-with-androi/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But question is how to rotate ImageView around moving path. I am not asking how to make ontouch event. I have moving ImageView and I need rotate it around curve path. Dynamically, angel depends on the situation if I am moving left, right, up, down.